# Facebook API persmission reset

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Working on iPhone application for facebook integration, i have already taken some of the permissions from the user as follow :

> data =     (
>                   {
>               "basic_info" = 1;
>               email = 1;
>               "friends_birthday" = 1;
>               "friends_photos" = 1;
>               installed = 1;
>               "public_profile" = 1;
>               "user_birthday" = 1;
>               "user_friends" = 1;
>               "user_location" = 1;
>               "user_photos" = 1;
>           }
>       );

Now I need one more permission from the user to post on his/her wall and that is `publish_actions`

I am using following code for gaining the user permission :

```
NSArray *permissionsNeeded = @[@"publish_actions"];

[FBSession.activeSession requestNewReadPermissions:permissionsNeeded
               completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
               if (!error) {
               [self makeRequestForPostOnMyWall];
               } else {
               NSLog(@"error %@", error.description);
                                                     }
                                                      }];
```

now it gives an error as follow :

> FBSDKLog: FBSession: a permission request for read permissions contains unexpected publish or manage permissions

By googling i came to know that you can not request these three permission togather namely "email,user_photos and publish_actions". But I need these three persmission and don't know how to do that, if any one knows has a solution for this then please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with @"publish_actions" action you need use `requestNewPublishPermissions` not use `requestNewReadPermissions` . and something else like email,user_photos, basicInfo you can request with `requestNewReadPermissions`